# How to upload file from Android to node.js server

Tags: android, node.js, image-uploading, multer, android-async-http

I am trying to send a file over http from android application to node.js server.

However, when I receive the file it's size is 0 bytes, 
although i can read the file's original name.

Do you have any idea what goes wrong here?

Here is the android part:

```
public class ImageUploader {

public static final String HTTP_LOCALHOST_8081_FILE_UPLOAD = "http://192.168.1.104:8081/file_upload";

public void upload(InputStream inputStream, String extension) {
    AsyncHttpClient asyncHttpClient = new AsyncHttpClient();
    RequestParams requestParams = prepareRequestParams(inputStream, extension);

    asyncHttpClient.post(HTTP_LOCALHOST_8081_FILE_UPLOAD, requestParams, new AsyncHttpResponseHandler() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(int statusCode, Header[] headers, byte[] responseBody) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(int statusCode, Header[] headers, byte[] responseBody, Throwable error) {
            error.printStackTrace();
        }
    });

}

private RequestParams prepareRequestParams(InputStream inputStream, String extension) {
    RequestParams requestParams = new RequestParams();
    requestParams.put("image", inputStream, "image." + extension, "image/jpeg");
    return requestParams;
}}
```

And here is the node.js part:

```
var express = require('express')
var multer = require('multer')
var app = express()
var path = require('path')
var uploading = require('./uploading/uploading.js')

var storage = multer.diskStorage({
  destination: function(req, file, cb) {
    cb(null, 'uploads/')
  },
  filename: function(req, file, cb) {
    cb(null, file.fieldname + '_' + Date.now() + path.extname(file.originalname))
  }
})

var upload = multer({
  storage: storage
})

app.use(express.static('public'));

app.post('/file_upload', upload.single('image'), function(req, res) {
  //uploading.openIrfanView(__dirname, req.file.filename)

  res.sendStatus(200);
})

var server = app.listen(8081, function() {})
```

My guess is that either java `inputStream` doesn't fit for http `multipart` request or I need to use some special node library to read what is send.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, i got it guys.

It's a thing I stumbled upon not for the first time - It's that reading from an input stream **empties it out**.

I obtained `inputStream` from `Uri`, then read from it for the first time to display it on the screen of the device and then for the second  time to pass it to `ImageUploader` and by that time the `inputStream` was already empty.

I probably should have pasted that fragment of code to the question.